# How to get current name of route(such as 'this' value)in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hardcode

I am a newbie of vueJS
and I would like to use the following template to start my project and I would like to convert it work with IE11

Link : codepen erickarbe/pen/pLbRqQ

The original code is:

```
computed: {

filteredMembers() {
  return this.members.filter(member => {
    
    let first = member.First.toLowerCase()
    let last = member.Last.toLowerCase()
    
    let fresult = first.includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) 
    let lresult = last.includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) 
     
    if(fresult)
      return fresult
    
    if(lresult)
      return lresult
  })
},
```

In order to work with IE11 and I try to use polyfill  and convert the code to

```
computed: {
filteredMembers: function(){  
  return this.members.filter(function(member){
    
    let first = member.First.toLowerCase()
    let last = member.Last.toLowerCase()

   //Error for 'this' 
    let fresult = first.includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase())  //'this' Error 
    let lresult = last.includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase())  //'this' Error 
   //Error for 'this'

    if(fresult)
      return fresult
    
    if(lresult)
      return lresult
  })
},}
```

I have Error When I using 'this' on  this.searchQuery.toLowerCase())

but I can solve it using 'var ths = this' like

```
 computed: {
    filteredMembers: function(){
      var ths = this;  
        ........
      let fresult = first.includes(ths.searchQuery.toLowerCase())
      let lresult = last.includes(ths.searchQuery.toLowerCase())
```

Is it very hardecode or stupid way to get 'this' value???

Is there any best way to get current 'this' value,Thank you very much

Comment: No, it's not very hard code, but recommand use Babel for doing this. You can check [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) to learn how to use webpack + babel with Vuejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read about how the [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485) keyword works in JavaScript.

You just need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the original `this` to the new function:

```js
return this.members.filter((function (member) {
  // ...
}).bind(this))
```

The extra `()` around the function may not be necessary, but I wasn't sure if IE11 would work without it.